# Placement of regex group

Tags: c#, regex

I have a token that looks like this `#foo bar#`

What I would like to do is use regex to do two things,

1. Identify the whole token i.e. `#foo bar#
2. Get just `bar` from the token

So far i am using this to get the whole token as a group `(?<group1>#foo [^#]+#)`

I am stumped as how to get `bar` as a second group?

I am trying variations of this, but not quite there yet, your help would be appreciated.

`(?<group1>#foo (?<group2[^#]+)#)`

Comment: Your idea seems good; does it work after you fix the missing `>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually pretty close. I got it working with this Regex:

```
(?<group1>#foo (?<group2>[^#]+)#)
```

(you were missing a closing `>` after group 2).

This program outputs `bar`:

```
var input = "#foo bar#";

var m = Regex.Match(input, "(?<group1>#foo (?<group2>[^#]+)#)");

Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["group2"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a small alteration to your regex and came up with this:

```
(?<group1>#foo (?<group2>[^#]+)#)
```

Example can be found here: http://regexr.com?33api